# Scroll based animated side panel menu conflicting with header animated menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a left panel menu that animates off and on screen by clicking a hamburger nav icon. The nav icon toggles between an open and close state displaying the hamburger icon and an X icon. There's also a top header menu that drops down when scrolling to a certain div and animates up again when scrolling to the top. When the header menu drops down while the left menu is on screen, the left menu animates back off screen and the nav icon resets. This all works perfectly fine but when after scrolling back to the top again you have to click the nav icon a few times to get the left panel to animate on to screen again. What is causing the left menu to get buggy after scrolling to the top?

```
// left panel animation
$('#nav-icon').click(function() {

$(this).toggleClass('open close');

if ($('#nav-icon').hasClass("open")) {

    $(".mobile" ).animate({"left":"0px"}, 200);

}

if ($('#nav-icon').hasClass("close")) {

$(".mobile" ).animate({"left":"-260px"}, 200);                                                                                                      
}

});



// top menu scroll animation
   $(window).on('resize load', function(){  

  if ( $(window).width() > 1024) {

    $('header').addClass('navDropDown');


    var statment = $('.homeStatement').offset();

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > statment.top - 200){                                                                        
            $('.navDropDown').stop().animate({ 'top': '0px' }, 75);
            $(".mobile" ).animate({"left":"-260px"}, 200); 
            $('#nav-icon').removeClass('open').addClass('close');                                   
        }

        if ($(window).scrollTop() < statment.top - 200){                                
            $('.navDropDown').stop().animate({ 'top': '-70px' }, 75);                           
        }


    }); 

}                               

});
```

Comment: Check your source in console when you scroll back to the top. See if your side drawer has the class open or closed attached (regardless of its actual state). You are blocking the click handler during animation with your `if` statements - so the button wont do anything until your blocking animation has completed.

Comment: Once scrolling back to the top the nav icon is getting a close class which is causing the drawer to close properly. But clicking the icon again it takes a few clicks to open the drawer back open. I also noticed when first loading the page and scrolling down then back up to the top the drawer gets the same clicking issue which is caused by the scroll function. Is there a better way to close the drawer than with the scroll? I tried basing it on a class added to the top menu when it when the top menu was on screen. The nav icon would toggle back to close class but the drawer wouldn't animate.

Comment: Yep, I get that. I beleive this is the culprit:
$(".mobile" ).animate({"left":"-260px"}, 200); 

you are forcing that animation on scroll, so it makes the drawer close. However, you block the opening until the scroll is done and the animation times out. Instead of running an animation on scrollTop for the drawer - how about just setting it to the closed position so you dont have to wait for the callback on the animation to complete before unblocking the handler.